# ASP .NET MVC 3 Entity Framework Disable Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing the ASP .NET MVC3 Music store tutorial and instead of connecting to the attached database EF is creating a new database in SQLEXPRESS (code first) . How do I prevent this happening.With the configuration I am using the EF should be connecting to existing database - not creating a new one.
I have a DbContext Class as below

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }   
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my web.config has the following Connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;         Integrated Security=SSPI;       
         AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcMusicStore.mdf;       User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Application_Start(), set your database initialization strategy to:

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MusicStoreEntities>(
         new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MusicStoreEntities>());
```

This will use the default initializer and will only create the database if it can't find it. There are actually three possibilities:

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

You can also do some custom initialization by using this in your Application_Start()

```
Database.SetInitializer<MusicStoreEntities>(new MusicStoreEntityInitializer());
```

Then, add a new class which derives from one of the three initialization types, depending on what you need.

```
namespace MusicStore.Models
{
  public class MusicStoreEntityInitializer : 
           CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MusicStoreEntityInitializer> 
  {
      protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntity context)
      {
         base.Seed(context);

         // your code to populate db with test data
      }
  } 
}
```

With this kind of set up, you have a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting a null initializer in the constructor of your db context or in `Application_Start`:

```
public class MusicStoreEntities: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }   
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public MusicStoreEntities(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MusicStoreEntities>(null);
   }
}
```

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) you might take a look at about EF Code First. And here's a [blog post](http://Database.SetInitializer%3CSchoolDBContext%3E%28new%20RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges%3CSchoolDBContext%3E%28%29%29;) explaining the different initialization options.